# Get 'popular categories' in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

i have 2 models `Books` and `Categories` and I'm wondering how i would get the top 10 categories by the amount of books they have in them.

My model looks like this

```
class Book(models.Model):
    """(Book description)"""
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

class Category(models.Model):
    """(Topic description)"""
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100)
```

Any help would be great,

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Aggregation and order-by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-by) in the Django documentation.

You should be able to do something like:

```
Category.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('book')).order_by('num_books')
```

This will give you a list of categories ordered by their popularity, and you can then display only the first (or last) ten using a slice.